# How zero or many, one or many, zero or one are crated in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, model

I have a `Vacancy` that can have zero or many `Benefits` and currently use a `ManytToMany` in Vacancy like this:

```py
class Vacancy(models.Model):
    benefits = models.ManyToManyField(Benefits)
```

My question is how can I define that there is a possibility that a Vacancy has no Benefit? And how can I define that it must have at least one benefit?

How does this apply to `OneToOne` and `ForeignKey` relationships **in django**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can pass `blank=True` as arugument in `ManyToManyField`.

```py
class Vacancy(models.Model):
    benefits = models.ManyToManyField(Benefits, blank=True)
```

This way `benefits` becomes optional.

Also you can check if `Vacancy` has benefits or not by using `.exists()` method.

```py
# benefits exists
if vacancy_object.benefits.exists():
    # do what you want
# benefits not exists
else:
    # do what you want
```